# Trouble with loading assets libgdx

Tags: libgdx, loading

I've been trying to create a loading screen, so that the game doesn't freeze when I go from a screen to another, I use this loading screen to load one asset (which is the background image).
My Assets class is defined as following:

```
public class Assets {

    public static final AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static void load(){
        manager.load("images/ObservatoryScreenBackground.jpg", Texture.class);
    }

    public static void dispose(){
        manager.dispose();
    }
}
```

I have the following code in my LoadingScreen:

```
    public LoadingScreen(ProjectSurvival game){
    super();
    this.game = game;
    Assets.load();
    while(!Assets.manager.update()){
        System.out.println("not loaded yet");
    }
    game.setScreen(new ObservatoryScreen(game));
}
```

The problem is that the game never exists from this while tread and keeps running, printing "not loaded yet"...

I also tried this in the render method:

```
    if(manager.update()) {
        game.setScreen(new ObservatoryScreen(game));
    }
```

The loading screen shows up for 1 second and just after that, the game crashes giving me this error:

```
    Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Asset not loaded: images/ObservatoryScreenBackground.jpg
```

I know there are similar topics, I did exactly what was told, but it doesn't seem to work to me...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly, you missed adding the asset causing exception to be loaded by manager. It thinks that everything loaded, but the specified item just wasn't processed.

Comment: From the code you provided it's not clear where/how you call something like manager.load("images/ObservatoryScreenBackground.jpg", Texture.class), thus it's not clear why it not loaded during manager.update() calls.

Comment: @Rinold Sry I forgot to put my Assets class code:

Comment: public class Assets {
    public static final AssetManager manager = new AssetManager();

    public static void load(){
        manager.load("images/ObservatoryScreenBackground.jpg", Texture.class);
    }

    public static void dispose(){
        manager.dispose();
    }
}

Comment: Don't know if this solves your problem but don't make your `AssetManager` `static` unless you know exactly what you are doing. The official documents warn you about this so I advice you to read these.